# To compute minmax of a function of two variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Find `min` `max` `f(x,y)`
given that, you have to maximize over and minimize over `y`.

Is there any direct command which can do computation?

Example:

```
 min max 0.5*log(x/1+y)

 s.t 0 < x < P and 0 < y < N where P and N are constants.
```

Comment: "maximize over and minimize over y". Maximize over what? Also over y? How does that make sense? But maybe you're saying you need to find the x such that the max over y is minimal? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Maybe you would need to do something like:

```matlab
if x>0 & x<P & y>0 & y<N
    minn = min(0.5*log10(x/(1+y)))
    maxx = max(0.5*log10(x/(1+y)))
```